# What's the difference between fdefiniton and function(special operator) in CL?

Tags: common-lisp

So I'm reading quicklisp code trying to understand it and learn from it.
I've seen this macro:

```
(defmacro neuter-package (name)
      `(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
         (let ((definition (fdefinition 'error-unimplemented)))
           (do-external-symbols (symbol ,(string name))
             (unless (fboundp symbol)
               (setf (fdefinition symbol) definition))))))
```

From what I know, the only difference between fdefinition and function(#') is that fdefinition is setf-able. Am I right?
If yes, wouldn't it be simpler(or maybe even more effective) to omit the let part, and change setf to

```
(setf (fdefinition symbol) #'error-unimplemented)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FDEFINITION` is a function. `FUNCTION` is a special operator. `FDEFINITION` thus gets an evaluated argument.

```
(setf (fdefinition symbol) #'error-unimplemented)
```

Above means to set the global function definition to the function `ERROR-UNIMPLEMENTED`. It could also be a lexical bound function with that name.

```
(flet ((error-unimplemented (...) ...))
  (neuter-package "FOO"))
```

Above would use the lexically bound function.

Note also that under some situations a Lisp compiler might assume that a particular current function `ERROR-UNIMPLEMENTED` is used. For example for inlining or calls without lookups.

**But the code uses `FDEFINITION`.**

```
(setf (fdefinition symbol) (fdefinition 'error-unimplemented))
```

Above will look-up at its runtime the global function from the symbol...

```
(flet ((error-unimplemented (...) ...))
  (neuter-package "FOO"))
```

Above would not use the lexically bound function.

Comment: I think both of your `setf` forms will have identical effect. Maybe you could rework your answer to contain more self-contained examples?

Comment: @sds: FDEFINITION will always lookup the global definition. `FUNCTION` can reference a lexically bound version...